# Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия ENTER в функции input() просто был перенос на новую строку (с возможностью вернуться к ней)

Tags: python, input, текст, ввод

Я делаю мини-игру, и в одном из заданий нужно написать собственное письмо. Нужно, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал ENTER, функция `input()` не завершалась, чтобы игрок мог вернуться и, например, что-то отредактировать.

Просто я не думаю, что ему будет удобно каждый раз писать `\n`, если он хочет начать новую строку.

Comment: Через input - никак, он такое не поддерживает. Можно через библиотеку prompt-toolkit: https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html?highlight=multiline#multiline-input

Comment: Можно использовать [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) (если поймёте как сделать выход из него по хоткею, оформите ответом, дам респектов)

Comment: Можете создать окно Tkinter и оформить там ввод

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
import sys
var = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Для выхода нужно нажать Ctrl + D

Comment: Не знаю как там под Windows, но под Linux этот вариант не позволяет редактировать строки выше.

Comment: Проверял на macos, странно что на linux это не сработает